# Python streamlit library installation test error

Tags: streamlit

I launch to the Spyder (Python 3.8) in Anaconda navigator. I install streamlit library successfully, then execute following command to be sure. So, the output is as following:

```
In[1]: pip show streamlit

Name: streamlit
Version: 1.23.1
Summary: A faster way to build and share data apps
Home-page: https://streamlit.io
Author: Snowflake Inc
Author-email: hello@streamlit.io
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: c:\users\rheyd\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages
Requires: altair, blinker, cachetools, click, gitpython, importlib-metadata, numpy, packaging, pandas, pillow, protobuf, pyarrow, pydeck, pympler, python-dateutil, requests, rich, tenacity, toml, tornado, typing-extensions, tzlocal, validators, watchdog
Required-by: 
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

but, when I want to test streamlit library by "streamlit hello", I can not due to following output:

```
In[2]: streamlit hello
  Cell In[2], line 1
    streamlit hello
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I execute streamlit library function test?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for some reason the streamlit executable is not in your PATH environment variable.
You can try the following command to import streamlit as a python module and execute it:

```bash
python -m streamlit hello
```

Otherwise you can try to restart the anaconda kernel as suggested in the bottom Note of the `pip show` command.

Comment: Exact Dear
Thanks a bunch.
I change my enviroment, and i can to install streamlit library as following:

Open CMD (no as administrator)
C:\Users>pip install streamlit 

If CMD open as administrator the default directory changes as following:

First step: C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Users
Second step: C:\Users>pip install streamlit